# How can I store date only in datetime field in WebMatrix with Sql Server CE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, webmatrix, sqldatatypes

I was wondering if there was a way to store a date (example: `01/01/2013`) as datetime without SQL Server CE adding the time (example: `12:00:00 AM`).

I could always store it as the string `"01/01/2013"` but I really want to be able to compare the dates on querying the database.

I realize that as long as I only stored the date part, all of the times in the datetime field would have equal values (i.e. `12:00:00 AM`), so comparing them wouldn't be a problem and I could just always ignore the time part, however, it seems ridiculous to have this unnecessary data appended to every entry in the table.

Is there a way to store only the date part of the datetime as datetime so that the dates can still be compared in the SQL query or do I just need to live with this overhead and move on?

**Side Note:**

I just spent the last 30 minutes searching Google and SO for an answer I was *sure* was already out there, but to my surprise, I couldn't find anything on this issue.

---

**Update:**

The conclusion I have come to is that I will just accept the time in the datetime format and let it always default to `12:00:00 AM` by only adding the date part during the INSERT statement (e.g. `01/01/2013`). As long as the time part always remains the same throughout, the dates will still be easily comparable and I can just trim it up when I convert it to string for screen display. I believe this will be the easiest way to handle this scenario. After all, I decided to use SQL for the power of its queries, otherwise, I might have just used XML instead of a database, in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you really can't get rid of the time component. It is part of the data type defined by sql server. I was very annoyed by it until I found that I could still display the dates without the time using JQuery to reformat them with the date formatter plugi:

https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Good Luck!

Comment: Well, I appreciate it. I will check that plugin out, but I'm not sure what it can do that I can't. I used to just store the date as string and convert it on the other side (or perhaps with SQL when I query the database to begin with), but it leaves me having to sort an array by date which isn't as much a pain as it is confusing, so I was hoping to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

select CONVERT(date, GETDATE())

Comment: If I am understanding your answer, this is a query and while it will select only the date part of the datetime field, the date + time will still be stored in the database. It won't be the end of the world if I have to end up doing it this way, but the whole purpose of this question is to find out if there is a way to store the date only part as datetime.

Comment: I dnt think so there is a way to store only date in "datetime" data type. But if you can then just alter the data type (date time to date). I sure you know that .

Comment: SQL Server CE has only one date associated data type and it is "datetime"

Comment: Ohhh ok. Dont know abt that.